# Edit xml file in php

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

I have an XML like this:

```
<Categories>
  <Category Code="3014" Name="category-a" MasterCode="3015" />
  <Category Code="3015" Name="category-b" MasterCode="3010" />
  <Category Code="3010" Name="category-c" MasterCode="0" />
</Categories>
```

I want to change this XML to this:

```
<Categories>
  <Category1>category-a</Category1>
  <Category2>category-b</Category2>
  <Category3>category-c</Category3>
</Categories>
```

I have tried a many sample code solutions without success.

Update. i solved this problem with this code

```
    foreach ($item->getElementsByTagName('Categories') AS $item2) {
    $tip = 0;
    foreach ($item2->getElementsByTagName('Category') AS $item3) {
        $tip += 1;
        $item2->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement('Category' . $tip, $item3->getAttribute('Name')));
        $delete[] = $item3;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a code sample you tried and explain what you got (errors or different result)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: i solved my problem also i shared my code thanks .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is your xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<root>
       <Categories>
        <Category Code="3014" Name="category-a" MasterCode="3015" />
        <Category Code="3015" Name="category-b" MasterCode="3010" />
        <Category Code="3010" Name="category-c" MasterCode="0" />
       </Categories>  
</root>
```

Here is your php file:

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load('safa.xml');
$delete = array();
$tip = 1;
foreach ($xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('Categories') AS $key => $item2) {
    foreach ($xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('Category') AS $key => $item) {
        $item2->appendChild($xmlDoc->createElement('Category' . $tip, $item->getAttribute('Name')));
        $delete[] = $item;
        $tip += 1;
    }
}
foreach ($delete as $del) {
    $del->parentNode->removeChild($del);
}
$XMLData = $xmlDoc->saveXML();
fopen('safa_dump.xml', 'w');
file_put_contents('safa_dump.xml', $XMLData);
```

Here is your dump xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <Categories>
        <Category1>category-a</Category1>
        <Category2>category-b</Category2>
        <Category3>category-c</Category3>
    </Categories> 
</root>
```

Comment: I'd really advise against writing code for people who haven't shared any or demonstrated any effort in solving the problem themselves.  It'll just lead to Stack Overflow getting treated like a free coding service.